# How to autotype multiple texts using javascript in automator onto an unfocused application

Tags: javascript

How do I execute commands such as typing at a series of short phrases with delays and repeats onto an unfocused application. For example, I want the javascript to be able to type out a infinite loop of a series of texts onto discord running in the background while I'm using chrome.
P.S I haven't really tried anything as of yet as I barely have any experience in coding, so I'm mainly looking for scripts at this point

Comment: You don't need to repost. Just use the "edit" link at the bottom to add details if required.

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far? Can you please copy/paste the code you have directly into the question above?